# flutter image picker maxDuration issue

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I'm using image picker plugIn from flutter.dev official. And now I'm facing weird issue with setting the maxDuration of choosing video. Following is my code now:

```
pickVideoFromGallery() async {
Navigator.pop(context);
File videoFile = await ImagePicker.pickVideo(
    source: ImageSource.gallery, maxDuration: const Duration(seconds: 10));
int helloInt = await videoFile.length();
int byebyeInt = videoFile.lengthSync();
print(helloInt);
print(byebyeInt);
setState(() {
  this.fileForThumbnailEXPRMT = videoFile;
});}
```

with the version of `image_picker: ^0.6.0+2`

I'm trying to set maxDuration of picked video for 10 seconds, so that user cannnot upload video over length of 10 seconds. Although I'm using deprecated method, I'm sure that maxDuration code must work just fine because all the other parts of imagePicker work just fine on all os and sw versions. But when I set the maxDuration to 10s and test it on the device, there happened nothing. I picked video of 3 minutes and the code didn't limited the process, which actually should not happen in my case. Am I misunderstanding the concept of maxDuration argument, or is my code wrong when setting maxDuration of video?

Does anyone know how to set maxDuration of video perfectly? I tried various ints for setting the maxDuration but it didn't work with all those ints.

Clear answers appreciated! Thank you in advance [:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with ImagePicker because of this plugin capture video by phone default camera app and you haven't access to check and manage duration while capturing until the user stops capturing and return to your application.

My advice would be to use Camera plugin https://pub.dev/packages/camera and use timer to stop recording.

Comment: Thank you for leaving answer, but I want to know what exactly does this maxDuration do, and how to properly use it..! Then how about choosing existing videos in gallery or photos? That actually doesn't limit users' on time recording duration but just choose among the existing videos.. W/hat made me think so it that the maxDuration argument does exist. If the maxDuration doesn't make change either on recording or choosing from gallery, why does that argument exist in the plugIn from official flutter dev team?

Comment: @ChansuPark I get what you are saying. In theory, based on what I managed to understand from maxDuration it was suppose to control the timing. However, I notice in practice it does not work that way. The only workaround I found to control the timing the start and stop of recording was to use the camera plugin.  I hope this answer your question.

Comment: thank you. I'm just trying to make it happen in another way. This did help me [: